# Redirecting subnet traffic to a different gateway

Tags: networking, router, routing, iptables, tomato

I have a Debian Jessie box at 192.168.1.5 connected to the router (at 192.168.1.1) running an OpenVPN client (it's actually a Pi using [this setup](https://gist.github.com/superjamie/ac55b6d2c080582a3e64). The only part different is that the Pi's eth0 IP is static because of the router, i.e., the Pi is using the router's DHCP).

When LAN clients are set to use 192.168.1.5 as their gateway, they are on the VPN, as intended.

What I need is to have LAN clients within 192.168.1.128/25 have all their traffic redirected to 192.168.1.5, even **when their IP is set by the router's DHCP** and their gateway becomes 192.168.1.1. In other words, **clients within 192.168.1.128/25 should work as if their gateway was 192.168.1.5.**

**What's the `iptables` and/or `route add` setup the router needs to have to do this** (the router runs Tomato 3.4-138)? These are the router settings:

## iptables -t nat -L -n

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
WANPREROUTING  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            wan_ip
upnp       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            wan_ip

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
SNAT       all  --  192.168.1.0/24       192.168.1.0/24       to:192.168.1.1
SNAT       all  --  172.16.1.0/24        172.16.1.0/24        to:172.16.1.1

Chain WANPREROUTING (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            to:192.168.1.1
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 to:192.168.1.1:443
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:2222 to:192.168.1.5:22
DNAT       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            to:192.168.1.4

Chain pupnp (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain upnp (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:55355 to:192.168.1.130:55355
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:55355 to:192.168.1.130:55355
DNAT       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:5353 to:192.168.1.48:5353
DNAT       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:4500 to:192.168.1.48:4500
```

## iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
shlimit    tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh state NEW
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
           all  --  anywhere             anywhere            account: network/netmask: 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 name: lan
           all  --  anywhere             anywhere            account: network/netmask: 172.16.1.0/255.255.255.0 name: lan1
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
wanin      all  --  anywhere             anywhere
wanout     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
upnp       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             SIP-Device

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain shlimit (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
           all  --  anywhere             anywhere             recent: SET name: shlimit side: source
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 hit_count: 4 name: shlimit side: source

Chain upnp (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             client-1                udp dpt:55355
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             client-1                tcp dpt:55355
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             client-2          udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             client-2          udp dpt:4500

Chain wanin (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             *Pi*               tcp dpt:ssh

Chain wanout (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

## route

(router sits behind WAN modem)

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
modem.ip.0.1    *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 vlan2
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
172.16.1.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br1
modem.ip.0.0    *               255.255.224.0   U     0      0        0 vlan2
127.0.0.0       *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
default         modem.ip.0.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 vlan2
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick way to override the DHCP-supplied default route (which is a /0) is to add two /1 routes to the VPN gateway:

***route -n add -net 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.5 128.0.0.0***

***route -n add -net 128.0.0.0 192.168.1.5 128.0.0.0***

While DHCP supplied default route remains in place, either of the /1s will be preferred for IPv4 traffic because of their shorter prefixes.

I'm currently using this hack as a proof-of-concept;  I'm still online, and a table query shows that the /1 route is being used.

```
[nevin-mac-mini:~] root# route -n add -net 0.0.0.0 192.168.2.1 128.0.0.0
add net 0.0.0.0: gateway 192.168.2.1
[nevin-mac-mini:~] root# route -n add -net 128.0.0.0 192.168.2.1 128.0.0.0
add net 128.0.0.0: gateway 192.168.2.1
```

```
[nevin-mac-mini:~] root# netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
0/1                192.168.2.1        UGSc            3        0     en0
default            192.168.2.1        UGSc            4        0     en0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              1     6576     lo0
128.0/1            192.168.2.1        UGSc            1        0     en0
...
```

```
[nevin-mac-mini:~] root# route -n get 200.200.200.200
   route to: 200.200.200.200
destination: 128.0.0.0
       mask: 128.0.0.0
    gateway: 192.168.2.1
  interface: en0
      flags: 
 recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    rttvar  hopcount      mtu     expire
       0         0         0         0         0         0      1500         0 
[nevin-mac-mini:~] root#
```

Comment: Not sure I follow. Add these routes to the Pi?

Comment: Add them to any device that would want to use the .5 host as a gateway, instead of the .1 device provided by DHCP.